# Oracle Client setup stops without finishing and without error messages

Tags: oracle, windows-10, installation, client

I'm trying to setup the Oracle 32-bit client on Windows 10 Enterprise.  it gets as far as the Summary step, where I click the "install" button.   A few seconds later the program stops, but doesn't install anything and doesn't issue any error messages.

What should I do?

PS I'm running setup as admin.  I aslo followed every bit of advice I could find to purge old oracle installs, including deleting %TEMP%\deinstall* , %TEMP%\OraInstall*, %TEMP%\CVU*, c:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory

and other things

I also re-downloaded the package and tried again to no avail

Comment: This is not a programming question. There is "super user" site for this. Try "run as administrator"

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am running as admin

Comment: Delete following folder if exist: `%TEMP%\deinstall*` , `%TEMP%\OraInstall*`, `%TEMP%\CVU*`, `c:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory`

Comment: For question like this, when it is basically Win10 related, you might find better help on "super user", or even "dba". What can I say? I can only say, that I stopped to using Oracle client and I use ODAC components.

Comment: Yeah I cross posted to dba.  @WernfriedDomscheit  I deleted those dirs before starting

Comment: Is your user member of local "Administrator" group? Starting "As administrator" does not work.

Comment: Did you check the log file in `%TEMP\%`?

Comment: I don't see a log file there from the time of the install or that looks like it has something to do with Oracle.  My account is not a local admin.  It is not permitted where I work. I have a different account to use for installs so I have to use run as admin.

Comment: I logged out and logged back in using the admin account.  However, the same thing happened.  The install exited without doing anything